# How to make PostgreSQL accurately increment by year fractions using interval?

Tags: postgresql, intervals

I'm attempting to increment a date by a fraction of a year, but when I compare the difference of the incremented time, it doesn't add up to the right fraction of the year (I'm using a non-leap year in this example)

This first example is incorrect from the third decimal place:

```
select ((extract(epoch from '2022-07-01'::timestamp + interval '1 year' * 0.45283595)) - extract(epoch from '2022-07-01'::timestamp)) / 31536000 
--= 0.454851895890408
```

I would expect it to be adding the equivilant of this, where I have calculated the number of seconds:

```
select ((extract(epoch from '2022-07-01'::timestamp + interval '1 second' * (31536000 * 0.45283595))) - extract(epoch from '2022-07-01'::timestamp)) / 31536000
--= 0.45283595000000276
```

Comment: Looks like bug or rounding issue. 
`select interval '1 second' * 31536000 * 0.45283595` gives `3966:50:34.5192`
`select interval '1 second' * 0.45283595 * 31536000` gives `3966:50:36.096`

Comment: Not every year is `31536000` seconds

Comment: It does if you do: `select interval '1 second' * (31536000 * 0.45283595); 3966:50:34.5192` and `select interval '1 second' * (0.45283595 * 31536000);  3966:50:34.5192`. Because: `select interval '1 second' * 0.45283595 ; 00:00:00.452836`.

Comment: `Not every year is 31536000 seconds ` - true but 2022 is so that doesn't explain the difference in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Adrian was on the right track. See below outputs, addings seconds doesn't yield the same results as adding a fraction of a year as it's computing it in terms of months (e.g. if we ask for 0.5 years, it adds 6 months, which isn't the same thing as splitting the year in half to the nearest second). Thanks for the responses.

```
select '2022-07-01'::timestamp + (interval '1 year' * 0.5) --2023-01-01 00:00:00
select '2022-07-01'::timestamp + (interval '1 month' * 12 * 0.5) --2023-01-01 00:00:00
select '2022-07-01'::timestamp + (interval '1 seconds' * (31536000 * 0.5)) --2022-12-30 12:00:00
```